# Stuck in condition on a circular doubly linked list In Java

Tags: java, list, if-statement, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

Im kinda new at coding so I guess that my issue should be pretty basic haha
Basically, Im working with circular doubly linked list in a Java program.
I had succesfully implemented the insert,print and other methods but im having some issues with two methods (search and remove).

I have a list class working succesfully with the insert code:

```
public class ListaDC {

    private NodoLCD head;
    private NodoLCD bottom;

    public void inserta(Planetas p) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new NodoLCD(p);
            bottom = head;
            bottom.setNext(head);
            head.setBack(bottom);
        } else if (p.getId() > head.getDato().getId()) {
            NodoLCD aux = new NodoLCD(p);
            aux.setNext(head);
            head = aux;
            bottom.setNext(head);
            head.setBack(bottom);
        } else if (bottom.getDato().getId() >= p.getId()) {
            bottom.setNext(new NodoLCD(p));
            bottom = bottom.getNext();
            bottom.setNext(head);
            head.setBack(bottom);
        } else {
            NodoLCD aux = head;
            while (aux.getNext().getDato().getId() > p.getId()) {
                aux = aux.getNext();
            }
            NodoLCD temp = new NodoLCD(p);
            temp.setNext(aux.getNext());
            temp.setBack(aux);
            aux.setNext(temp);
            temp.getNext().setBack(temp);
        }
    }
```

Here is a snap of my Node class:

```
private Planetas dato;
    private NodoLCD next;
    private NodoLCD back;

    public NodoLCD(Planetas dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }
```

It has all the getters, setters and toString

And I have another class called planets with some variables as name, position, type

The thing is that both methods are failing on the same part (if condition):

```
public boolean existe(int id) {
        boolean esta = false;

        if (head!= null) {
            if ((id >= head.getDato().getId()) && (id <= last.getDato().getId())) {
                NodoLCD aux = cabeza;
                while (aux != bottom&& aux.getDato().getId() < id) {
                    aux = aux.getNext();
                }
                esta = (aux.getDato().getId() == id);
            }
        }
        return esta;
    }
```

This is my code for the search method and it never enters into the first if, even tho there are ID that match the request.

Am I missing something? Do you guys need more information or code?

Thanks in advance for your time :) I really appreciate it

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think we have nearly enough information to help solve this. Consider reading [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some tips on how to create code snippets that are easy for us to reproduce your issue

Comment: Hi @SilvioMayolo thanks for your comment, I just added some more information. Do you think that is enough? Thanks again :)